# Updating a page everytime I revisit the page in CupertinoNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, sql-update, state-management, sqflite, data-storage

I am working on an app where the user can store list items as favorites using the SQFlite package. The function works well except one thing. The page where the stored favorites are display does not refresh properly. It only refreshes when restarting the app, not everytime a new items gets stored. Does anyone have a solution for that? I am trying to write a update function for the favorites page but can not get it working. Here is my code:
https://github.com/nic0501/favorites-sqflite.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using data streams for continuous updates, [Streams in Dart](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams).